# Android audio calls using android's sip

Tags: android, sip

I  developed an application for a customer to internet calling  using sip.For that he  provided me two valid sip user_id and password.  Am Using SIP API for SIP implementation.customer says that the call is not going.he don't get any notification about missed calls when he logged using his account.i cant find any mistakes in the code.please help me .the code is given below.

```
public class CallActivity extends Activity {
        public String sipAddress = null;
        public SipManager mSipManager = null;
        public SipProfile mSipProfile = null;
        public SipAudioCall call = null;
        Button b1;
        TextView sipadd;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.calling);
            sipAddress = (String) getIntent().getExtras().get("sipAddress");
            b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sipcallbtnend);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();
                }
            });

            sipadd = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sipcalltvdialedaddress);

            sipadd.setText(sipAddress);
            b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (call != null) {
                        call.close();
                    }
                    finish();
                }
            });
            initializeManager();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            // When we get back from the preference setting Activity, assume
            // settings have changed, and re-login with new auth info.
            initializeManager();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (call != null) {
                call.close();
            }

            closeLocalProfile();

            // if (callReceiver != null) {
            // this.unregisterReceiver(callReceiver);
            // }
        }

        public void initializeManager() {
            if (mSipManager == null) {
                mSipManager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
            }

            initializeLocalProfile();
        }

        public void initializeLocalProfile() {
            if (mSipManager == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (mSipProfile != null) {
                closeLocalProfile();
            }
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
            String username = prefs.getString("namePref", "");
            String domain = prefs.getString("domainPref", "");
            String password = prefs.getString("passPref", "");

            if (username.length() == 0 || domain.length() == 0
                    || password.length() == 0) {
                // showDialog(UPDATE_SETTINGS_DIALOG);
                return;
            }

            try {
                SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username,
                        domain);
                builder.setPassword(password);
                builder.setDisplayName(username);
                builder.setAuthUserName(username);
                mSipProfile = builder.build();

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i,
                        Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
                mSipManager.open(mSipProfile, pi, null);
                //
                //
                // // This listener must be added AFTER manager.open is called,
                // // Otherwise the methods aren't guaranteed to fire.

                mSipManager.setRegistrationListener(mSipProfile.getUriString(),
                        new SipRegistrationListener() {
                            public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                                // updateStatus("Registering with SIP Server...");
                                Log.d("onRegistering",
                                        "Registering with SIP Server...");
                            }

                            public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri,
                                    long expiryTime) {
                                // updateStatus("Ready");
                                Log.d("onRegistrationDone",
                                        "RegistrationDone..Ready");

                            }

                            public void onRegistrationFailed(
                                    String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                                    String errorMessage) {
                                // updateStatus("Registration failed.  Please check settings.");
                                Log.d("onRegistrationFailed", "RegistrationFailed");

                            }
                        });
            } catch (ParseException pe) {
                // updateStatus("Connection Error.");
            } catch (SipException se) {
                // updateStatus("Connection error.");
            }

            initiateCall();
        }

        public void closeLocalProfile() {
            if (mSipManager == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                if (mSipProfile != null) {
                    mSipManager.close(mSipProfile.getUriString());
                }
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                Log.d("WalkieTalkieActivity/onDestroy",
                        "Failed to close local profile.", ee);
            }
        }

        public void initiateCall() {

            // updateStatus(sipAddress);
            Log.d("nzm", "initiatecall");

            try {
                SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
                    // Much of the client's interaction with the SIP Stack will
                    // happen via listeners. Even making an outgoing call, don't
                    // forget to set up a listener to set things up once the call is
                    // established.
                    @Override
                    public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
                        call.startAudio();
                        call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                        call.toggleMute();
                        Log.d("on call established", "on call established");
                        // updateStatus(call);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
                        // updateStatus("Ready.");
                        // Intent i = new
                        // Intent(getBaseContext(),DialActivity.class);
                        // startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                };

                call = mSipManager.makeAudioCall(mSipProfile.getUriString(), sipAddress,
                        listener, 3000);
                Log.d("call", "" + call.getState());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall",
                        "Error when trying to close manager.", e);
                if (mSipProfile != null) {
                    try {
                        mSipManager.close(mSipProfile.getUriString());
                    } catch (Exception ee) {
                        Log.i("WalkieTalkieActivity/InitiateCall",
                                "Error when trying to close manager.", ee);
                        ee.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                if (call != null) {
                    call.close();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

The permissions in manifest is given below

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_SIP" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sip.voip" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="true" />
```

please help me .Thanks in Advance.

Comment: hi i am assigned voip using sip as a project in university.And i am facing alot troubles. Have u got it working? If yes then can u plz send me the project, as the android sample isn't working. I'll be very thankful

Comment: I am so sorry that my app is not working.. if i can find anything which will be helpfull to you ,then i will inform you.please post  your mail  id to noufalm786@gmail.com

Comment: @Noufal I have a bad problem about working with SIP. If you found any solution I'll be happy to know. Please see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25520246/local-voip-call-with-sip

Answer (score 4):

Maybe add these

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CONFIGURE_SIP" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.software.sip" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.software.sip.voip" android:required="true" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Are you using the android's example? It should work on device that support SIP.

And add receiver in onCreate

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
callReceiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();
this.registerReceiver(callReceiver, filter);
```

Comment: Thanks.I edited the code upon your suggetions.but still not working.

Comment: i got some positive response from the application.i got a log inside the @override onRingingBack(SipAudioCall call).But not sure any end caller will receive the call.which sip account is suitable for testing.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have this in manifest?:

```
<receiver android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver" android:label="Call Receiver"/>
```

See:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html
and
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SipDemo/