# Local VoIP call with SIP

Tags: android, sip

I wanna make SIP peer to peer VoIP call in android. This call should be made in local network without any need to access to internet. In fact I don't want to use any external server to register the profiles. But I don't know what to write in serverDomain in profile builder.
This is the constructor

```
public SipProfile.Builder (String username, String serverDomain)
```

Suppose that one ip is 192.168.1.2
and the other is 192.168.1.3

So in initializing function what should I pass as serverDomain to the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the URI in the From: header comes out as username@ServerDomain, so your local IP address would be OK. There is not enough other information there for any registration going on anyway.

Comment: Thanks but Like how? like this? "target@192.168.1.3" while the target's ip is 192.168.1.3?

Comment: More likely to be the local one and use setOutboundProxy for the target.

Comment: Can you write some code please? I don't know what you mean. Or any example about this? because I found nothing on internet except that everybody said this is possible without mentioning how.

Comment: This page should help:
 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipProfile.Builder.html

Just create SipBuilder with your local details and then call setOutboundProxy with the remote address. But I'm not an Android developer and I only know about SIP so that's the best I can do.

Comment: My problem has nothing to do with android programming dude. This is all SIP issues. And yes I have visited that page. There's not enough clarification about how to do this and even that did't explain how to use setOutboundProxy(). I'm totally confused. I don't have any idea on what to write for serverDomain parameter.

Comment: serverDomain - your own ip address eg 192.168.1.2. setOutboundProxy - the remote one eg 192.168.1.3. Just try it and see what happens.

Comment: if you mean this :
SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder("TestUser", "192.168.1.2");
builder.setOutboundProxy("192.168.1.3");

then registeration fails with errorCode -9

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60098/discussion-between-user3194963-and-user2808671).

Comment: Hi. Did you found the answer ? I have the same question.